# Using svn via ssh as a local environment

Tags: svn, ssh

I'm mounting a server in Ubuntu using Nautilus and FTP.  For Facebook development, working on the files on the server makes the development cycle easier and quicker.

I'm trying to set up a "local" svn repository on the server...to do so, I connect to the server using the terminal and ssh and run the commit and update commands.

My problem is, when I do svn update, it changes the file ownership from "ftpuser:psacln" to "root:root"...which is causing problems for apache.

Is there a way to configure the repository, or svnserve, to maintain the file ownership?

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 1):

[Subversion and file permissions](http://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2005/04/27/subversion-and-file-permissions/)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm interested in the meta-data-versioning - owner-group-mode patch...just having trouble finding the "Building from a Tarball" file.  Did you use that option?

Comment: It's all in a long INSTALL help file. http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/branches/meta-data-versioning/owner-group-mode/INSTALL

Comment: Yeah...just realised the patch is done prior to the subversion install...I'll give the other options a look...thanks again.